# Override the link CSS with h3 style

Tags: css

I'm working on a page where I show an image and then have text at the bottom that's a link to a specific page.

By default the link is colored gray, but I want to override that and have the text picking up the h3 style.

Here's the CSS:

```
h3{
color: #a60000;
font-size: 20px;
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
font-family: mpluslight;
}

a {
color: #CCC;
font-weight: normal;
}
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<h3><a href="http://mydomain.gr/">Personal Training</a></h3>
```

I tried by changing the h3 values to '!important' but that didn't work.

I'm trying to avoid using inline CSS. Trying to keep my code as clean as possible.

Any ideas?

Comment: After writing the post the answer clicked! Instead of trying to override using the 'h3' I just created a new class and connected the link to that.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to do this:

```
h3 a { color: #a60000; }
```

... or possibly this:

```
h3 a { color: inherit; }
```